# How to convert this C# scripts to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, code-conversion

I have a C# script like below:

```
public List<MazePath> BreakIntoConnectedPaths()
{
    List<MazeVertex> remainVertices = new List<MazeVertex>(vertices);
    List<MazePath> paths = new List<MazePath>();
    while (remainVertices.Count > 0)
    {
        MazePath path = new MazePath();
        path.entrancePosition = entrancePosition;
        path.exitPosition = exitPosition;
        VisitCell(path, remainVertices.First(), null, remainVertices);
        paths.Add(path);
        //Store the coordinate for entrance and exit 
    }
    return paths;
}

void VisitCell(MazePath path, MazeVertex ver, MazeVertex parent, List<MazeVertex> remainVertices)
{
    remainVertices.Remove(ver);
    path.Add(ver);
    for (int i = 0; i < ver.connectVertices.Count; i++)
    {
        MazeVertex ver2 = ver.connectVertices[i];
        if (ver2 != parent)
        {
            VisitCell(path, ver2, ver, remainVertices);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to convert it to javascript as below

```
BreakIntoConnectedPaths = function() {
    var remainVertices = _.cloneDeep(this.vertices);
    var paths = [];

    while (remainVertices.length > 0) {
        var path = new Path();
        path.entrancePos = this.entrancePos;
        path.exitPos = this.exitPos;
        this.VisitCell(path, remainVertices[0], null, remainVertices);
        paths.push(path);
        // Store the coordinate for entrance and exit
    }
    return paths;
}

VisitCell = function(path, vertex, parentVertex, remainVertices) {
    _.remove(remainVertices, function(v) {
        return v.x === vertex.x && v.z === vertex.z;
    });
    path.Add(vertex);
    for (var i = 0; i < vertex.connectVertices.length; i++) {
        var connectedVertex = vertex.connectVertices[i];
        // if (parentVertex && (connectedVertex.x !== parentVertex.x || connectedVertex.z !== parentVertex.z)) {
        if(parentVertex && _.isEqual(connectedVertex, parentVertex)) {
            VisitCell(path, connectedVertex, vertex, remainVertices);
        }
    }
}
```

The `_` symbol here is [lodash](https://lodash.com/) sign.

After I convert to javascript code, the behavior of these functions is difference with the C# one. With the same `vertices` data, the `paths` array had returned with difference size.
Thanks you for reading and pls help me if you see my mistake here.

Comment: "The behavior is different" doesn't really tell us much about the problem.

Comment: Mention the exact error message, you are getting!

Comment: After I convert to javascript code, the behavior of these functions is difference with the C# one. With the same `vertices` data, the `paths` array had returned with difference size.

Comment: An example what goes wrong would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the C# version, your VisitCell function has a condition that says `if(ver2 != parent)`, but in the JS version you check that they are *equal* instead of *not equal*.

Also, that condition would never pass any way because in your first call to that function you pass in `null` for the parent, but in that condition you check that the parent is "truthy".

Lodash's `isEqual` can handle null values, so I'm not sure why you're checking if the parent is truthy there. Perhaps you meant to do this?

```
 if(!_.isEqual(connectedVertex, parentVertex)) {
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right, thank you. 
My stupid mistake is check that parentVertex. 
For the _.isEqual this is my mistake when edit the code in the question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to improve your JavaScript code. When transpiling code, it is better to not copy/paste and fix, but to rewrite using the target language instead.

I would prefer to have this written, for example:

```
var vertices;
var entrancePos;
var exitPos;

function Path(entrancePos, exitPos){
    this.entrancePos = entrancePos;
    this.exitPos = exitPos;

    this.Add = function() {
        // your Add() code here
    }
}

function breakIntoConnectedPaths() {
    var remainingVertices = _.cloneDeep(vertices);
    var paths = [];

    while (remainVertices.length) {
        var path = new Path(entrancePos, exitPos);
        visitCell(path, remainingVertices.shift());

        // Store the coordinate for entrance and exit
        paths.push(path);
    }

    return paths;
}

function visitCell(path, vertex, parentVertex) {
    path.Add(vertex);

    for (var i = 0; i < vertex.connectVertices.length; i++) {
        var connectedVertex = vertex.connectVertices[i];
        if(_.isEqual(connectedVertex, parentVertex)) {
            visitCell(path, connectedVertex, vertex);
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the variables `vertices`, `entrancePos`, `exitPos` and `Path` are not available to me on your C# code, so I only declare them on JavaScript. Implement them as you may.

Does that fix it, by the way?

Comment: Thanks you for your code. I think your code is very nice in structure. I had tested this in the first time I convert the script but the whole project use this function in many way, I don't know know but the result is still wrong when use remainingVertices.shift(). I had voted up your answer but it can't not public view because my reputation is very low. Thanks you again.

Comment: As asked in your OP, we would need to have some result examples to know why or how the codes differ. Just looking at it, seems to me the results should be equal